# Best way to modify Array: Array 1 has X values. Array 2 has a subset of these. Modify every object that matches Array 2 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = [{ id: id1, value: false}, {id: id2, value: false}, id: id3, value: false}]

array2 = [id1, id2]
```

What I want to do is compare these two, and for every match on ID in `array2`, I want to set the value to `true`. So in the example above, I would like to modify my `array1` (or create a new one) to:

```
array1 = [{ id: id1, value: true}, {id: id2, value: true}, {id: id3, value: false}]
```

Both arrays are dynamically created, I don't know their size. But `array2` is never larger than `array1`, and `array2` can also be empty.

Today I have solved this by doing a double for each:

```
array1.forEach(element => {
  array2.forEach(element2 => {
    if (element.id== element2) {
      element.value= true;
    }
  });
});
```

But I believe that this can be done in a much better way? I feel that the .map() function may help me out here, but I haven’t grasped it fully yet.

Bonus question, `array2` is in fact just a string that looks like this: `"id1; id2".` I convert it to an array with `var array2 = string.split(";");` Is there a smoother way to just compare the whole string to `array1` instead of creating an array out of it?

Comment: Do those arrays contain unique elements?

Comment: `array1.forEach(o => { o.value = array2.includes(o.id); });`

Comment: @ChrisG, that overwrites a possible `true` value for an id which is not in the other array.

Comment: @NinaScholz right; this will only work if `array1` starts out with only `false`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function for creating a different array (you can also use [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to change the current one) and in the condition use [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the second array contains the item's `id`.

I also have used object destructuring (`...`) to create another item objects int the `mapped` array to have entirely different array with different items.

```js
const array1 = [
   { id: 'id1', value: false}, 
   { id: 'id2', value: false}, 
   { id: 'id3', value: false}]
   
const array2 = ['id1', 'id2'];

const mapped = array1.map(item => array2.includes(item.id) ? { ...item, value: true } : {...item});

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was sure I could use array.map(), just haven't grasped it to its full extend yet :)

Comment: `map` and `...` are used to observe the immutability

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the possible performance issues. If arrays 1 and 2 have M and N values, it will take M×N operations to iterate through every possible pair. This might take a long time if both M and N are large. However, it looks like each element in array 1 has a unique ID. If this is the case, one option is to use a map (sometimes called a dictionary or associative array) instead of an array to index the values by ID, and then modify them if necessary.

```
const array1 = [{ id: id1, value: false}, {id: id2, value: false}, id: id3, valu;e: false}]
const array2 = [id1, id2];

// Use a plain object as a map.
const array1byID = {};
array1.forEach((val) => { array1byID[val.id] = val; });

// Modify the values in the object
array2.forEach((ary2ID) => {
  if (array1byID has ary2ID) {
    array1byID[ary2ID].value = true;
  }
});

// array1 will now be updated since it shares elements with array1byID.
```

This will only take N operations.

If the entries in array 1 *don't* have unique IDs, you're better of using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store the values of array 2. A **Set** can test if an element is included using `Set.has()` ***much faster*** than an array can using `indexOf()` or `find()`. In that case, the code would be:

```
const array1 = [{ id: id1, value: false}, {id: id2, value: false}, id: id3, valu;e: false}]
const array2 = [id1, id2];

// Use a plain object as a map.
const set2 = new Set(array2);
array1.forEach((el) => {
  if (set2.has(el.id)) {
    el.value = true;
  }
});
```

If you have a lot of arrays of things with IDs, you should probably consider using maps instead. A helpful explanation why can be found in the article [You might not need arrays](https://medium.com/@david.gilbertson/you-might-not-need-arrays-3f0e6bf25d69). The title exaggerates the case a little bit, but if you're just doing create-update-delete stuff, the ideas are well worth exploring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I belive map wil do the trick in my case :)

Comment: If `array2` is going to have less than 20 entries, it probably will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for getting the object for an update.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 'id1', value: false }, { id: 'id2', value: false }, { id: 'id3', value: false }],
    array2 = ['id1', 'id2'];
    
array2.forEach(i => array1.find(({ id }) => id === i).value = true);

console.log(array1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code, with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
array1 = [{ id: 1, value: false}, {id: 2, value: false}, {id: 3, value: false}];
array2 = [1, 2];

array1.forEach(element => {
    if (array2.indexOf(element.id) != -1) {
      element.value= true;
    }
});

console.log(array1);
```

You can use [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) too:

```js
array1 = [{ id: 1, value: false}, {id: 2, value: false}, {id: 3, value: false}];
array2 = [1, 2];

array1.forEach(element => {
    if (array2.includes(element.id)) {
      element.value= true;
    }
});

console.log(array1);
```